# To split multiple columns into rows based on delimiter using shell

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I have a tab-separated file that looks like this:

```
cg13201342  F   ARNT;ARNT;ARNT;CTSK 3'UTR;3'UTR;3'UTR;TSS1500
cg05269359  F   SCN4B;SCN4B;SCN4B;SCN4B 3'UTR;3'UTR;3'UTR;Body
cg06018296  R   NEK3;NEK3;NEK3;NEK3 3'UTR;3'UTR;3'UTR;Body
cg05172994  F   WDR20;WDR20;WDR20;WDR20 3'UTR;3'UTR;3'UTR;Body
```

Desired output:

```
cg13201342  F   ARNT   3'UTR
cg13201342  F   ARNT   3'UTR
cg13201342  F   ARNT   3'UTR
cg13201342  F   CTSK   TSS1500
cg05269359  F   SCN4B  3'UTR
.
.
```

and so on

I tried

```
awk 'BEGIN {
       FS = OFS = "\t"
     }
     {
       n = split($3, f, " *;*")
       for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
         print $1, f[i]
     }' probe-genes-regions >chk
```

but that is only splitting the third column. I want the last column to split together with the second column and form rows with 1st field of 3rd column and 1st field of last column and so on respectively

Comment: Hi. We're not a free code writing service, but we can help you arrive at a solution on your own. Please describe what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hi, Please provide more details and the code you wrote to do it, so someone will try to help you

Comment: Ah, I see now, you want to "explode" each line into multiple ones based on the last field?  It would be good if you could say this explicitly in the question itself. Also mention what to do with duplicate lines in the output.

Comment: I want to explode each line based on second and third and last field. Need output also as tab delimited. I can remove duplicate fields with sort -u later

Comment: Note that `;*` matches on *zero* or more `;`s so `" *;*"` also matches one the empty string. Maybe you meant `" *; *"` instead.

Comment: Can you please explain how you came up with the output corresponding to `cg13201342`?  There are seven sub-fields in the 3rd column, but your expected output contains four rows.  Knowing what this format is and what the different things mean (I'm a bioinformatician), I would not expect you to split `CTSK 3'UTR` into two separate strings.

Comment: Is that space in `CTSK 3'UTR` REALLY a tab? It doesn't look like it in your example, it looks like a blank given how the rows don't line up at that space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split fields 3 and 4 on semi-colon into seperate arrays, then iterate over them, e.g. (assuming field 3 and 4 have the same number of elements):

*parse.awk*

```c
BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }

{ 
  n = split($3, a, /;/); split($4, b, /;/)
  for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    print $1, $2, a[i], b[i] 
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk infile
```

Output:

```
cg13201342      F       ARNT    3'UTR
cg13201342      F       ARNT    3'UTR
cg13201342      F       ARNT    3'UTR
cg13201342      F       CTSK    TSS1500
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   3'UTR
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   3'UTR
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   3'UTR
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   Body
cg06018296      R       NEK3    3'UTR
cg06018296      R       NEK3    3'UTR
cg06018296      R       NEK3    3'UTR
cg06018296      R       NEK3    Body
cg05172994      F       WDR20   3'UTR
cg05172994      F       WDR20   3'UTR
cg05172994      F       WDR20   3'UTR
cg05172994      F       WDR20   Body
```

Comment: Note that this appears to split `WDR20 3'UTR` into two fields, at least the way the output is written in the answer. Also, when I run this on the original tab-delimited data, I only get three columns of output. Are you assuming the user has first pre-processed the data somehow?

Comment: Also note that `length()` generally returns the length of a string.  If you use a particular `awk` that supports returning the length of arrays, then you need to mention which one it is (probably GNU `awk`, right?).

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yes I was assuming tsv input, the edit removes that assumption. I tested this script with GNU awk, mawk, busybox awk and nawk. I don't know of any awk that does not support length on arrays.

Comment: `length(array)` is not POSIX. bwk added it to his one in 2002, but you can imagine that some BSD or SysV based systems are still based on earlier versions. In any case, you can do `n = split(...)` like in the OP's code to avoid having to use `length(array)`.

Comment: Still, you are splitting `$4` and the input only has three (tab-delimited) fields... The `WDR20 3'UTR` is the data in one of the sub-fields of the third tab-delimited field.  This is, I believe, GFF data, and the `;`-delimited field may contain any number of such sub-fields.

Comment: @Kusalananda, the input sample has 4 whitespace delimited fields though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sigh, yes it has, but that space is data, not a delimiter. The 3rd field is a list of "annotations" such as "the gene name is WDR20", "this is the 3-prime UTR", "this is the 3-prime UTR of the WDR20 gene", "the sample is from the this particular tissue", etc.

Comment: @Kusalananda: reliance on `length(array)` removed, it now also works with `gawk --posix`. Wrt columns 3 and 4 not having the same size, that is left as an exercise for the user

Comment: @Kusalananda, you'd need to bring it up to the OP as the expected output does split that `CTSK 3'UTR`, and Thor's answer works as requested.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The OP says "tab-delimited data", and also refers to "the 1st field of the last column" (assuming they mean `;`-delimited there, unless you somehow want to infer space-delimited). I think that's pretty clear.

Comment: @Kusalananda, *"form rows with 1st field of 3rd column and 1st field of last column and so on respectively"* suggest the last column is the one after the third.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas In that case, the OP simply does not understand their own data. Splitting `CTSK 3'UTR` into two things would be a bug, from a bioinformatician's point of view. It's like saying `Stéphane Chazelas` is clearly two different things and not one name.

Comment: @Kusalananda, which is why I'm saying you should bring it up to the OP. Thor's answer as written addresses the OP's requirement and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`):

```bash
sed 's/;/\t/' file | mlr --nidx --fs tab nest --evar ';' -f 4
```

This first uses `sed` to replace the first `;` on each line with a tab, separating the third tab-delimited field into two separate fields.  GNU `sed` can insert a tab character using `\t` with the `s` command, but not all `sed` implementations may.  If your's can't, then type a literal tab character in place of `\t` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Miller then reads and writes tab-delimited data (`--nidx --fs tab`) and will "explode" (or "un-nest") each record based on the `;`-delimited sub-fields of the fourth tab-delimited field (`nest --evar ';' -f 4`).

The output, given the data in the question:

```
cg13201342      F       ARNT    ARNT
cg13201342      F       ARNT    ARNT
cg13201342      F       ARNT    CTSK 3'UTR
cg13201342      F       ARNT    3'UTR
cg13201342      F       ARNT    3'UTR
cg13201342      F       ARNT    TSS1500
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   SCN4B
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   SCN4B
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   SCN4B 3'UTR
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   3'UTR
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   3'UTR
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   Body
cg06018296      R       NEK3    NEK3
cg06018296      R       NEK3    NEK3
cg06018296      R       NEK3    NEK3 3'UTR
cg06018296      R       NEK3    3'UTR
cg06018296      R       NEK3    3'UTR
cg06018296      R       NEK3    Body
cg05172994      F       WDR20   WDR20
cg05172994      F       WDR20   WDR20
cg05172994      F       WDR20   WDR20 3'UTR
cg05172994      F       WDR20   3'UTR
cg05172994      F       WDR20   3'UTR
cg05172994      F       WDR20   Body
```

Passing this through `uniq` would remove duplications of adjacent lines.

---

Using only `awk`:

```bash
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
    {
        nf = split($3,a,";")
        for (i = 2; i <= nf; ++i) print $1, $2, a[1], a[i]
    }' file
```

This splits the third field on `;` and then, for the second sub-field on of the third field, proceeds to output the first two fields together with the first sub-field of the original third field.

The output of this is identical to that of the pipeline at the top of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using any POSIX awk and no matter what the spaces are in your input:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:];]+' -v OFS='\t' '{
    n=(NF-2)/2; for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print $1, $2, $(2+i), $(2+i+n)
}' file
cg13201342      F       ARNT    3'UTR
cg13201342      F       ARNT    3'UTR
cg13201342      F       ARNT    3'UTR
cg13201342      F       CTSK    TSS1500
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   3'UTR
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   3'UTR
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   3'UTR
cg05269359      F       SCN4B   Body
cg06018296      R       NEK3    3'UTR
cg06018296      R       NEK3    3'UTR
cg06018296      R       NEK3    3'UTR
cg06018296      R       NEK3    Body
cg05172994      F       WDR20   3'UTR
cg05172994      F       WDR20   3'UTR
cg05172994      F       WDR20   3'UTR
cg05172994      F       WDR20   Body
```